# Is there a way to open a folder in Mac with Windows Explorer in the virtual machine under VMware Fusion?

Tags: windows, macos, virtual-machine, windows-explorer, vmware-fusion

I have installed Windows 7 in my Mac with VMware Fusion. When I want to open a folder in Mac that is shared with the virtual machine in Windows Explorer, I usually launch Windows Explorer in the virtual machine and navigate from the home folder to the destination by many clicks. Is there a way to make this easier? Ideally, a service or an Automator action that is accessible from context menu would be great.

You would have to pass the file path information from Mac to Windows, and control the behaviour of Windows Explorer from Mac. Maybe, it’s hard to do, but I’m still curious.

Answer (score 0):

This idea is not that cool, but just a little bit nicer than browsing from the home folder each time.

Use **Automator**. The following procedure assumes that you have the shared folder in the virtual machine contains some folders in Mac OSX's home folder, such as `Desktop, Dropbox, and Documents`. If you have many folders at different places in your system, you would have to write conditional statements for each folder in the JavaScript below.

1. Install **Get File Path.action**. See http://www5.wind.ne.jp/miko/mac_soft/automator_actions/pgs/GetFilePathAMA-en.html for more information.
2. File > New > Service
3. "Service receives selected "**files or folders**" in "**Finder**" at the top
4. Add "**Get File Path**" action to the workflow. Choose "POSIX (Unix)".
5. Add "**Run JavaScript**" action to the workflow.
6. Add the following code. Edit as you need.

   ```
   function run(input) {
       var B = input[0]; // property name is 0
       C = B.replace(/\u002f/g, "\\"); // convert the file separators
       var D = C.replace(/^\\Users\\myusername/, "Z:"); // Edit this line as needed. 
       //For example, you may have D: drive instead.
       return D;
   }
   ```
7. Add "**Copy to Clipboard**" action to the workflow.
8. Save the service.
9. Now select a file or folder that is shared with the virtual machine. Click **Finder** > **Service** > and select the service you just created. Then go to the Windows Explorer of the virtual machine and paste the clipboard content to the address bar of the Explorer..